# No option to switch dalvik to art on galaxy s5 android 5

Tags: dalvik, art

I was looking for an option to switch from dalvik to art on my galaxy s5 g900f with Android 5,but it was not in the place it should be. Is it because of the Android version? Or maybe only one of them is available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're right, Android 5.0 (and 5.1 for that matter) uses only ART.

Comment: Thank you,  I was wondering because of some ago that said that I have dalvik. Probably bad app

Comment: Dalvik version 2.0.0 and above is ART